# UploadError 403 in swfupload for Firefox

Tags: java, tomcat, swfupload

I'm trying to upload files using swfuploder and it works fine in IE.But its getting "UploadError 403" in Firefox. I'm using apache-tomcat-6.0.16 and couldnt access the `.htaccess` file as well.

This is my code to use for swfupload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>SWFUpload Demos - Simple Demo</title>
        <link href="../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfupload/demos/swfupload/swfupload.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfupload/demos/simpledemo/js/swfupload.queue.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfupload/demos/simpledemo/js/fileprogress.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swfupload/demos/simpledemo/js/handlers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var swfu;
            window.onload = function() {
                var settings = {
                    flash_url : "../js/swfupload/demos/swfupload/swfupload.swf",
                    upload_url: "upload_pages/uploader.jsp",
                    post_params: {"PHPSESSID" : ""},
                    file_size_limit : "100 MB",
                    file_types : "*.*",
                    file_types_description : "All Files",
                    file_upload_limit : 100,
                    file_queue_limit : 0,
                    custom_settings : {
                        progressTarget : "fsUploadProgress",
                        cancelButtonId : "btnCancel"
                    },
                    debug: true,
                    prevent_swf_caching: true,

                    // Button settings
                    button_image_url: "../js/swfupload/demos/simpledemo/images/TestImageNoText_65x29.png",
                    button_width: "65",
                    button_height: "29",
                    button_placeholder_id: "spanButtonPlaceHolder",
                    button_text: '<span class="theFont">Upload</span>',
                    button_text_style: ".theFont { font-size: 16; }",
                    button_text_left_padding: 12,
                    button_text_top_padding: 3,

                    // The event handler functions are defined in handlers.js
                    file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
                    file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
                    file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
                    upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
                    upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
                    upload_error_handler : uploadError,
                    upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
                    upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,
                    queue_complete_handler : queueComplete
                };

                swfu = new SWFUpload(settings);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h2>File Upload</h2>
            <form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="fieldset flash" id="fsUploadProgress">
                    <span class="legend">Upload Queue</span>
                </div>
                <div id="divStatus">0 Files Uploaded</div>
                <div>
                    <span id="spanButtonPlaceHolder"></span>
                    <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel All Uploads" onclick="swfu.cancelQueue();" disabled="disabled" style="margin-left: 2px; font-size: 8pt; height: 29px;" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried with both absolute and relative url for "upload_url" but the same error "uploadError 403" appears.But it works for IE.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code 403 means [Forbidden](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4). This is an authentication error. The request requires an authenticated user (logged-in user), but either the user isn't there in the session, or the associated session cannot be found.

I have never used SWFUpload, but it look like that it didn't pass the `jsessionid` cookie along with the request to the server side, so that the server side cannot identify the client. Googling "[swfupload jsessionid](http://google.com/search?q=swfupload+jsessionid)" also learns that you're not the only one who encountered this particular problem. To fix this, you need to append the `jsessionid` to the URL in the settings:

```
upload_url: "upload_pages/uploader.jsp;jsessionid=${pageContext.session.id}",
```

That said, the following line

```
post_params: {"PHPSESSID" : ""},
```

looks suspicious as well. What is an empty PHP session ID doing there in a JSP/Servlet environment? Aren't you overlooking/forgotting this while copypasting someone else's code?

Comment: I'm trying the simple upload demo example given in http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm.. Well post_params: {"PHPSESSID" : ""}, doing nothing here. This code works for IE.. I have append the jsessionid to the URL.But still the same error 403 occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Im having a similar problem but in apache/PHP. So im linking a possible solution here.

From what i've found so far it seems to be a security issue with the session authentication on the server in which you have security extensions installed (ie session protection/encryption) which makes the server think that html page and swf uploader are different users thus causing the 403 error. http://imagevuex.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=4337

Also check that mod_security is disabled and try adding these .htaccess settings, it seems to work for some.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Another solution seems to be (also .htaccess), from http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2010/01/05/swfupload_0_0-error-http-status-403-solved/

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Content-Type “^multipart/form-data;” “MODSEC_NOPOSTBUFFERING=Do not buffer file uploads”
```

Finally firefox might be a cookie bug found here http://topecoders.blogspot.com/2010/06/solution-for-flash-cookie-bug.html